# removing an extra column from a resume template

Tags: margins, cv

So I downloaded a resume template here: [the template `.tex` file](http://links.tedpavlic.com/tex/tpavlic_cv_faculty.tex). Basically after the first `\section{Contact Information}` section, I'd like everything left aligned. The reason is that I am making a cover letter to go along with the CV and want the header to look the same. Here is how it looks like

[image]

Is it possible to shift the "dear madam" and the remaining paragraphs over one "column". I feel like the problem is when the template author defines the section part.

Answer (score 2):

The actual page is set up with a very large margin paragraph width that contains the sectional units. Here's a view on the first page with you set with the `showframe` key added to [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry):

[image]

To stick with the current setup, you need to add to your preamble

```
\usepackage{changepage}
```

and then use

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{-\marginparwidth}{0pt}
  <your letter content here>
\end{adjustwidth}
```

to have content set in such a way that it spans across the entire page (including the "pseudo" column on the left).

[image]

Comment: Okay thanks, that works. Another quick question. If I remove a line from header (say, `Associate Research Scientist` and the `fax` line from the two columns), instead of pushing the text up, it leaves a blank space. It other words, it aligns with "information" instead of "contact" in the `\section` column

Comment: @masfenix: For each entry that you remove, you need to remove the ``\\`` as well. Based on that, everything is aligned appropriately.

Comment: Yes I did that, but the blank line stays there.

Comment: @masfenix: Ahhh... change the three `\parbox` usages inside the `tabular` to `\parbox[t]`. The first/last don't have that `[t]`op alignment, while the middle one has a `[m]`... change them all to `[t]`.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, but introduced a lot of extra space at the bottom now. Also, do you mind explaining what the `\parbox[t]` does for learning purposes?

Comment: @masfenix: `\parbox[t]` sets the anchor point for the `\parbox` to be at the baseline of the first line inside the box. This is what is considered to be the top of the `\parbox`, from a textual perspective. The middle column - designating the space - is actually useless. So remove it altogether. You'll see it sets a `\parbox[t][5\baselineskip]` (you've changed it from `[m]` to `[t]`) which makes it's height fixed at `5\baselineskip`. That is 5 `\baselineskip`s... equivalent to 5 lines of text.